# Texmfhome on windows : main directory grouping macros, biblatex files

Tags: macros, root

I want to specify a directory for all my macros and biblatex so that i avoid to copy and paste between folders for my editing.

I heard about Texmfhome but it is on Linux, so how can i configure it on Windows ? 
Thanks

I use Tex-Studio.

Comment: Which distribution do you use?

Comment: I am on windows 10 and for TexStudio 2.12.4

Comment: That doesn't tell me what the TeX distribution is. TeX Studio is only an editor. Do you have MiKTeX or TeX Live?

Comment: Yes i do have MikTeX on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to create a directory for that, say TeXMFhome, or TeXMFlocal or whatever, the validate it for MiKTeX.

For this, launch  `MiKTeX Options` as `Administrator` if you want all files in this directory be available to any user of your computer`, as`User` if you want it  just for yourself.

Click on the `Roots` tab,  then on the `Add…` button, select your directory and click on `OK`.

Don't forget this directory must be `TDS-compliant`, i.e. the subdirectories must be organised with the TeX Directory Structure (same structure as the main root directory).

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, please to use the directory and the file : i just copied the macro file in this directory but how can i manage to compile it ? Is it just by typing (`\include{macros}` in the preamble ?)

Comment: Yes. Call it `mymacros.sty` or something, and don't forget to refresh the FNBD.